# InstallShield rollback backup directory?

Tags: installshield, rollback

When InstallShield is about to overwrite a file, it first create a copy of that file, so that in case of some installation error and the installation needs to abort, The system could be restored to its original state (rollback).

I would like to know where is that directory?

Comment: Are you referring to an InstallScript package or an MSI? MSI packages are handled by Windows Installer automatically, not by InstallShield. Also, can you give us more details about what you need to do? Perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: I am referring to InstallShield project of type InstallScript.
I think every installer does pretty much the same thing because if an error happens during installation they are all required to return the system to the state it was before the installation started.

Comment: The reason I want to know is because I want to run some generic program that compares configuration file of the installed version and the version being installed.

Answer (score 0):

The backup directory is different from machine to machine, and from setup to setup. you can find out by reading the installation log. See http://resources.flexerasoftware.com/web/pdf/archive/msi_writing_to_the_log_file.pdf

Comment: I did not find any reference in that article to that backup directory. or where I can find it.